# Ant Cannot Copy Error

Tags: ant, jenkins, copy

I'm running an ant build through Jenkins and on the stage where it is deploying to windows-share its returning the following error:

Failed to copy FILE to FILE2 due to failed to create the parent directory for FILE2 (I've taken the paths out to keep the question shorter).

I'm guessing that there might be some problem with permissions with the jenkins default user but this problem has only just started occurring, and any help would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a pretty old question but I thought I'd come back and complete it with a short update as to what was actually going on. Someone had changed the password for the user that was logged on to the vm that jenkins was running on, and when it was trying to create the directory to stick the files into it was running into permissions errors. Only problem was the error message wasn't very descriptive.

So in the end this was an infrastructure problem rather than anything to do with the ant script.

Answer (score 0):

I take it you're doing something like this:

```
<copy file="${from.dir}/${from.file}"
    tofile="${to.dir}/${to.file}"/>
```

And, you're getting an error that `${to.dir}` doesn't exist.

In earlier versions of Ant, you definitely had to create the directory before doing a copy:

```
<mkdir dir="${to.dir}"/>
<copy file="${from.dir}/${from.file}"
    tofile="${to.dir}/${to.file}"/>
```

I think I also noticed that later versions of Ant will create the directory for you when that directory didn't exist. I've always been in the habit of putting `<mkdir/>` in front of any task that creates a new file in a new directory, including things like `<zip/>` and `<tar/>`.

Here are some questions:

- Do your users also use Ant to run their builds? I know that this isn't always the case. Many users use Eclipse and don't bother with Ant.
- Is the version of Ant your users have vs. what your users have the same?
- Do you do a clean? Jenkins can emulate a clean either by doing an update, reverting and removing unversioned element, or by simply creating a brand new working directory. If your users don't remove the destination directory where `${to.file}` is being placed, it might work locally, but not on Jenkins.
- Can you manually run Ant from the Jenkins working directory. If so, what results do you get? (Remember to disable this Jenkins job before doing this. You don't want Jenkins to do a build while you're experimenting in the working directory.)